# Elastic Beanstalk migration fail for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Error message on website

```
An unhandled lowlevel error occured. The application logs may have details.
```

Log out put is

```
=== puma startup: 2015-05-17 16:26:01 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2015-05-17 16:26:01 +0000 ===
[3112] - Worker 0 (pid: 3150) booted, phase: 0
2015-05-17 17:31:54 +0000: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:51:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
2015-05-17 17:31:54 +0000: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:51:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
2015-05-17 17:35:47 +0000: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:51:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
2015-05-17 17:35:47 +0000: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:462:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call
```

But I dont believe that the secret_key_base is missing. I switched out the ENV[:secret_key_base] with the actual production key. If i go to my secret.yml file it is there in plain text.

I have nginx and puma running.

Possible error may be because the production secret_key_base is different from what got deployed? I did a rake secret after I eb deployed. I'm going to try deleting th eb instance and redoing it. Maybe that will resolve the issue.

I appreciate any other suggestions

Comment: couple of questions: did this ever work? how are you setting the environment? (it is complaining about the production env). Did you try adding couple of debug sentences to validate the assumptions you are making?

Comment: This works locally. I can visit my localhost. It never worked on the aws instance. Is it possible to place a debugger while running it on aws?

Answer (score 0):

`secrets.yml` isn't uploaded to the server. You need to set your secrets in the Elastic Beanstalk console.

Go to the environment, then select `Configuration` in the sidebar, select the gear icon next to `Software Configuration`, then add your key, presumably `secret_key_base` at the bottom of the list, click the `+` and then select `Apply`, and your environment should update.

I'd recommend a reboot after you add the key. If necessary, redeploy the most recent version and it should migrate successfully.

Side note (regarding debugger):
You can get a rails console by SSH-ing into the server.

1. Execute `eb ssh` from your Rails project directory.
2. Execute `sudo su -` to gain root access.
3. Execute `cd /var/app/current` to get into the Rails project directory.
4. Execute `bundle exec rails console` or `rails c` (depends on version) to get a Rails console.